# Can I translate my website with Google Translate?

Tags: google-translate

I have a web page created in English. Depending on the 
continent, I want to dynamically translate my whole webpage to another
language.

The webpage is fairly complex, so I cannot do it string by string. I just want to do it in a way like at the time of loading it will get translated into desired language.

Can I translate my webpage using the Google Translate API?

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example to to add Google translator to web page to translate specific element:

```
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head> 
<body> 
    <div class="translate">Тестирование</p>
    <div class="translate_control" lang="en"></div>

    <script>
    function googleSectionalElementInit() {
      new google.translate.SectionalElement({
        sectionalNodeClassName: 'translate',
        controlNodeClassName: 'translate_control',
        background: '#f4fa58'
      }, 'google_sectional_element');
    }
    </script>
    <script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleSectionalElementInit&ug=section&hl=en"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/maxim75/H3Wkr/ - working example

Answer (score 1):

You could add a Google Translate widget to you page and users can translate to their language of choice on demand. http://www.google.com/webelements/#!/translate

Comment: Ok good to hear that, Thanks Piskvor and abraham, To Abraham --- its requirement that page should get automatically translated so I cannot add a widget. to Piskvor --- Could you give me a code example. That will really help me.

Answer (score 1):

By visiting [google translate tool](http://translate.google.com/translate_tools) it generate a code that you add in your website.

It's also possible directly by using a url

```
http://www.google.com/translate?sl=XX&tl=YY&u=http://www.trial.com
```

where xx is the original language, yy the language to translate...

Maybe my tutorial will be helpful: [google translate](http://websource.heliohost.org/index.php/client-side-programming/item/16-translate-your-website-to-any-language-using-google-translate).

Comment: I don't see how that page could be helpful to the question asked. You've also failed to indicate it's your own website.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. See Google Translate API documentation here: http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html

Note that automated machine translation is, as of 2011, not an adequate match for human translation, so don't expect that the translated text will be perfect - it will probably be understandable with effort, but it will be obvious that it's machine-translated.

Comment: According to that page, Google is cutting support for this API December 1, 2011.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use microsoft translator API.. you can find the implementation at
http://code.google.com/p/micrsoft-translator-php-wrapper/
and you can see the demo also
http://renjith.co.in/translate/

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div>
        <select @change="translate()">
            <option value="en">English</option>
            <option v-bind="selectedLang" value="fr">French</option>
            <option value="es">Spanish</option>
            <!-- Add more language options as needed -->
        </select>
        <!-- <button @click="translate">Translate</button> -->

        <h1 ref="heading">hi</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="js">
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selectedLang: 'en',
      resultText: ''
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async translate() {
      const sourceText = this.$refs.heading.textContent.trim();
      const targetLang = this.selectedLang;

      const url = `https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=auto&tl=${targetLang}&dt=t&q=${encodeURIComponent(
        sourceText
      )}`;

      try {
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        const translation = response.data[0][0][0];
        this.resultText = translation;
        this.$refs.heading.textContent = translation;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Google translate in vue 2 using google api

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).